# Display xml feed with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to display a xml feed with xslt, the xml feed requires authentication is this possible?

How would I get the xml feed into the xslt?

Answer (score 1):

XSLT can be performed by a variety of processors. The answer to your question depends entirely on how the processor you are using obtains the XML feed.

If your processor is manipulated from a programming language, you can use that language to fetch the XML file from that language using authentication credentials before passing it to the processor.

Comment: I want to grab the xml feed with XSLT

Comment: That would depend entirely on what XSLT processor you are using, and how it handles the document() function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an interessting link for you...  The MYYN already answered your question..it is possible.

This link is an good starting point:
[XML,XLST with CSS Example](http://www.xefteri.com/articles/show.cfm?id=24)

If you have further questions regarding "Displaying an XML Feed"..please update your question.

Answer (score 0):

this is the one of oldest site. and uses asp for rss feed.

http://alabalikyagi.weblebici.net/rss.asp and uses a predefined template rsspretty.xsl

you can develop a simple username/password mechanism before serving the page.